# Trouble cutting down object to required info

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a config that contains an object with all the relevant information regarding my system. Part of it lists all of the ranks currently in the system:

```
return (object) array(
    //User Ranks
    "Ranks" => (object) array(
        "Developer" => (object) array(
            //Admin, User, Banned, Deactivated, Pending Moderation, Pending Email Activation
            "AccountState" => "Admin",
            //Page View Permission
            "PagePermissions" => array(
                "cadet/dashboard",
                "admin/dashboard",
                "admin/users"
            ),
            "TaskPermissions" => array(
                "BasicUserSearch",
                "AdvancedUserSearch",
                "GetRanks",
                "EditUser"
            )
        ),
        "Staff" => (object) array(
            "AccountState" => "Admin",
            //Page View Permission
            "PagePermissions" => array(
                "cadet/dashboard",
                "admin/dashboard",
                "admin/users"
            ),
            "TaskPermissions" => array(
                "BasicUserSearch",
                "AdvancedUserSearch"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

What I need to do is turn this object into a simple array to return to an AJAX call. The array must look like:

```
(
   "Developer" => array("AccountState" => "Admin), 
   "Staff" => array("AccountState" => "Admin)
)
```

I tried doing this with this code:

```
public function GetRanks(){
    $LstRanks = (array)$this->config->Ranks;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($LstRanks); $i++){
        $LstRanks[$i] = array_column($LstRanks[$i], "AccountState");
    }
    return json_encode(["data" => 0, "ranks" => $LstRanks]);
}
```

However, the first line of the function returns null resulting in the loop constantly looping and producing errors. What is the best way to cut the object down like shown?

Error

```
[30-Apr-2017 18:38:47 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/thomassm/public_html/php/lib/UserSystem.php on line 23
[30-Apr-2017 18:38:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/thomassm/public_html/php/lib/UserSystem.php on line 23
```

Comment: The first line returns null? What does that mean? Which line? 'Returns'?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the error message in. Check the question now. Sorry for that.

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what is going on here with the code you've provided but if you want to make an array that contains some subset of the data of another array, the simplest thing to do is to iterate over the array (with `forearch`) and add the data you want to a new array. What you are doing seems rather convoluted.

Comment: try use `foreach ($LstRanks as $role => $Lstoptions) {
foreach($Lstoptions as $options => $value){
//your logic }}` and keep use foreach to iterate if the $value is an array.

Comment: @arisalsaila the main issue is turning the object into the array. Once that's done I should be able to handle to looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function GetRanks(){
    $Ranks = (array) $this->config->Ranks;
    $LstRanks = array();

    foreach($Ranks as $StrRank => $LstRankInfo){
        $LstRanks[$StrRank] = $LstRankInfo->AccountState;
    }

    return json_encode(["data" => 0, "ranks" => $LstRanks]);
}
```

This is my solution using the advice from the comments. It seems that I was incorrectly turning the object into an array.